# How to redirect a list of human readable paths to another command?

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, locate

When working with the output of commands such as `locate` which produce lists of paths in "human readable form" (i.e. without `\` in front of spaces), how do you redirect their output to another command?

The output of `$ locate [something]` produces paths with spaces in them, which inhibits other programs to use the paths in the case they contain spaces. For example, if I were to

```
$ du -h `locate *.doc`
```

this will produce an error on all files and directories that contain spaces. (wrapping the ticks in spaces does not work)

Comment: Honestly, this is the second time I've had this problem in two days, in a different context.

Comment: We got confused. Is the solution bellow with `find` or `locate -0` acceptable? If not, why?

Comment: In the cases where the list of human readable paths is separable/separeted  by ASCII NULL characters it is an acceptable answer. The solution bellow might thus not be as generalizable as I had meant, but if I had a procedure for making sure that the list produced by `command1` is NULL separated `$ [command1] | xargs -0 [command2]` will accomplish what I want.

Comment: Using `locate -0` or `find -print0` as advised in bellow answer will generate a null separated list of files/paths; xargs will handle this null byte separation and will feed correctly `du` utility.  So, bellow answer is your solution. There is nothing more rigid to overcome special chars (like spaces) in filenames/pathnames than using tools which support null byte separated results (and both locate and find can null separate their results)

Comment: @rien333 - there is no such thing as a "list of human readable paths separated by null chars".  If the items in your list are null separated then the list is no longer "human readable"...

Comment: @don_crissti yes, but I meant human readable to apply to "paths" and not to the list of those paths.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I agree with your point on that a tool should supply such an option, but I wouldn't know whether most actually do. I guess if I were to write a program myself I could easily format the output within the program.

Comment: @rien333 It all depends on what you want to do. In your question obviously you need to get the disk size of some files. This is why you use `du` and `locate`. Hopefully `locate` supports `-0` = null separation on results; then we have `xargs` tool to handle null separators => all good , your goal achieved (and alternatively you could use `find -print0`). For another job, that you might use a tool not capable to provide null separated results you need to apply different techniques . But as far as you work with filenames using `find -print0 | xargs -0 ` is your solution to almost everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the specific reason you're using `locate`?  This appears to do what you have asked for:

```
find . -type f -name '*doc' -exec du -h "{}" \;
```

That said, if you *really* do want do use a tool like `locate` or `find` and pass its input as parameters to another program, you can avail yourself of the `NUL` delimited output and input that some tools provide.  `locate` and `find` both have an option (`locate`'s `-0` and `find`'s `-print0`) which will allow you to have more programatically-friendly output, which `xargs` is designed to read with *its* `-0` argument:

```
find . -type f -name '*doc' -print0 | xargs -0 du -h

locate -0 '*doc' | xargs -0 du -h
```

Comment: While I understand that I should be using `find`, I would rather know how to do this in a nice manner anyway. I personally do prefer locate however because 1. i am a noob 2. the syntax seems simpler 3. habits/it gets the job done.

Comment: I'm still wondering if you can do this without `-0` flags, but if you use `locate -0` this answer works for my example.

Comment: I made my question a bit more general, sorry.

Comment: `-0` is the magic sauce that makes this work.  It uses a `NUL` character explicitly to delimit the returned entities, and `xargs` is told to expect this, so whitespace is not used for parameter separation.  Happily, `locate` also has a `-0` parameter.

Comment: @DopeGhoti In case of find you could use `find -exec` instead of piping to `xargs`, right?

Comment: True, `find . -type f -name '*doc' -exec du -h "{}" \;` does work; I for some reason was thinking that it would run `du` for each result found.  I blame the fact that it's Monday.

Comment: Yeah, Monday is always a difficult day. I would suggest to include this -exec option in your answer (as an alternative) and also to advise a locate -0 solution since OP seems a bit confused about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want/need to pass the same line to multiple commands, something like this would work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

T="${IFS}" # Save off the Internal Field Separator

IFS=$'\n' # Set it to newline.

while read file_line
do
        echo "--"
        echo "${file_line}"
        echo "--"
done <<< $(locate $1) 
IFS="${T}  # Set it back to the original IFS.
```

It's a good idea to wrap *any* variables that might have spaces in "".

Answer (score 0):

Leaving command substitutions (`$(...)` or the `` `...` `` archaic form) unquoted invokes split+glob (split only in zsh) in Bourne-like shells.

The splitting is done on characters of the `$IFS` special parameter which contains space, tab and newline (and NUL in zsh) by default, which explains why your command doesn't work for file names that contain space characters.

You could do:

```
(IFS='
' # split on newline only
set -o noglob # disable glob
du -hc -- $(locate '*.doc'))
```

But that would still fail if there are file names that contain newline characters. The output of `locate` is simply not post-processable.

Most `locate` implementations have a `-0` option to output the file paths `NUL`-delimited. NUL being the only byte value that can't occur in a file path, that means that output is post-processable. You just need to split on NULs.

In `zsh`:

```
IFS=$'\0'
du -hc -- $(locate -0 '*.doc')
```

Or, better, using an explicit split-on-NUL operator:

```
du -hc -- ${(0)"$(locate -0 '*.doc')"}
```

In `bash` 4.4+, that could be:

```
readarray -td '' files < <(locate -0 '*.doc')
du -hc -- "${files[@]}"
```

That still leaves two problems:

1. If `locate` doesn't find any file, `du -hc --` will be run without arguments, which means it will give you the disk usage of the current working directory.
2. If on the other hand `locate` finds many files, you may end up reaching a limit of the `execve()` system call and get a *arg list too long* error.

Both problems can be avoided by doing:

```
locate -0 '*.doc' | xargs -r0 du -hc --
```

(`-r` and `-0` being non-standard extensions from the GNU implementation of `xargs` like `-h` is a non-standard extension from the GNU implementation of `du`).

That however introduces a new problem: `xargs` will run `du` several times to work around the `execve()` limit, but that means you'll get several `total` lines and also disk usage for a file hard linked several times may end up being counted several  times.

Thanks to `-r`, `du` won't be run if `locate` doesn't find any file, but that also means you won't get a `0 total` line.

With recent versions of GNU `du`, those problems can be addressed with:

```
locate -0 '*.doc' | du --files0-from=- -hc
```

This time, the list of files is passed via a pipe instead of via arguments, so  there's no limit of size of arguments. That also means no need to allocate large amounts of memory to store that list, and that `du` can start working on it as soon as `locate` starts outputting it.